# How to execute .sql script or query from Oracle SQL> prompt in multiple remote instances?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I' trying to execute .sql script or query from SQL> prompt into multiple instances.

But I'm unable to execute it in this way.

```
SQL> conn username/password@REMOTE @sqlscript.sql
OR
SQL> conn username/password@REMOTE @select name from v$database;
```

Definitely, I've some other ways to complete my task to execute like below:

```
M:\> echo select d.name, p.profile, p.limit from dba_profiles p, v$database d where resource_name = 'PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION' and profile in ('USERS','SERVICEACCOUNTS'); | sqlplus username/password#77@remotestring
```

But I'm looking in different way, Please find below my execution along with error from **SQL>** Prompt:

```
SQL>
SQL> conn username/Password@remotestring @tt.sql
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYS
KM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
    <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SQL>



SQL> conn username/Password@remotestring @select name from v$database;
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYS
KM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
    <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SQL>
SQL>
```

It should give a query output.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: @Rajesh How many instances do you need to connect to and how often do you need to run this?  If the numbers are small then something like Dmitry's answer should work well.  But if you need to frequently query a thousand databases there are better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

create environment variable `SQLPATH`

for example.  Windows

```
C:\sql>echo %SQLPATH%
c:\sql
```

create file `c:\sql\login.sql`

```
set linesize 10000
select name from v$database;
@@init.sql
```

create file `c:\sql\init.sql`

```
select sysdate from dual;
```

Test

```
C:\sql>sqlplus  /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Apr 4 22:41:52 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SQL> conn system/manager
Connected.

NAME
---------
ORCL


SYSDATE
---------
04-APR-19

SQL> conn system/manager@ORCL
Connected.

NAME
---------
ORCL


SYSDATE
---------
04-APR-19

SQL>
```